# wordpress registered menu doesn't show up

Tags: php, wordpress

i found this in wordpress and i don't know if it's a bug or what , i have registered a nav menu

like so: `register_nav_menu('primary', 'Theme Header Primary Menu');`

when i try to show my menu :

```
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'     => 'primary',
            'depth'              => 5,
            'container'          => false,
            'menu_class'         => '',
            'item_spacing'       => 'discard',
        ));
```

the menu doesn't show but when i change primary to something like main_menu in both functions or when i use

```
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'     => 'primary',
            'depth'              => 5,
            'container'          => false,
            'menu_class'         => '',
            'item_spacing'       => 'discard',
        ));
```

it shows up

can someone help please ? thanks in advance

Comment: Your theme probably _has_ registered a menu for that location name already. For example the WP default themes use that name, see https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/blob/trunk/functions.php#L74

Comment: Aside from what CBroe said (which is likely the cause of your problem), you have a typo there: `menue` should be `menu` (see [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters)).

Comment: yeah i have deleted all other wordpress themes and it worked fine. thank you guys

Comment: In your title, do you really intend to write 'sass', or do you mean 'WordPress'?

Comment: yeah i'm really sorry i had a question about sass then i changed it

Answer (score 0):

not used themes and plugins should be deleted: i think this was the issue